# Is there any better algorithm to find partition number p(n) than Euler's Pentagonal number theorem

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, space-complexity

[Euler's Pentagonal number theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2675382/calculating-integer-partitions) is a known dynamic programming-based solution to find partition number of n, denoted by p(n). Its time and space complexity is O(n^2\log(n)).

Is there any improvement over this algorithm to reduce complexity or is there any proof telling reducing complexity bellow this is impossible or NP-hard?

Comment: Proofs are better asked at https://cs.stackexchange.com/.  But time complexity is always at least space complexity (because it takes time to access space), and space complexity is the necessary space to write down all those numbers, so I don't see that there is much room to improve either.

Comment: @btilly Ok. But is there any better approach to reduce time and space complexity? The algorithm is very old and was proposed originally as a mathematical approach.  So from the algorithmic point of view can there be any further modification?

Comment: I'm not aware of better.  And for the reason I gave, it seems unlikely.  But that doesn't mean it doesn't exist.